# jquery '$.when': how to trigger 'done' callback even in case of error

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, .when

Jquery's `$.when` function executes the 'done' callback when all promises are resolved, but not if any of them result in errors. How do I execute the 'done' callback once all the promises have had a result, either `success` or `error`?

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kdLbLq25/2/

Answer (score 1):

> Jquery's $.when function executes the 'done' callback when all promises are resolved, but not if any of them result in errors.

Allow me to rephrase that in more accurate terminology.

jQuery's `$.when` takes a **list of promises**<sup>1</sup> and **returns a new promise**. That new promise **fulfills** when all of those promises fulfill or **rejects** when any of those promises reject.

The function you're looking fall is called "Settle" and is unavailable in jQuery's promise implementation - luckily we can easily add it.

The strategy is:

- Create a new promise explicitly.
- Keep a counter started at `n` - the number of arguments.
- For each argument:

  - If it's not a promise  assign it immediately and decrement the counter.
  - If it's a promise wait for it to resolve and then decrement the counter.
- When the counter reaches 0, resolve the promise.

```
$.settle = function(promises){
    var count = arguments.length; // how many we'll have to wait for
    var d = $.Deferred(); // the new deferred - representing the return value

    var results = []; // what we'll end up resolving with

    $.map(arguments, function(arg, i){
        if(typeof arg.then !== "function"){ // it's not a promise!
            results[i] = {status:"fulfilled", value: arg}; 
            count--; // and we don't have to wait for it
        } else {
            arg.then(function(value){
                results[i] = {status:"fulfilled", value: value };
                count--;
                if(count === 0) d.resolve.apply(d, results); // resolve promise
            }, function(e){
                results[i] = {status:"rejected", reason: e };
                count--;
                if(count === 0) d.resolve.apply(d, results); // resolve promise
            });
        }
    })
    return d.promise(); // return a promise over the deferred

}
```

The usage of the above should something like:

```
$.settle($.get("firstUrl"),$.get("secondUrl")).then(function(firstResult, secondResult){
     // access results here, values are in firstResult.value
     // and you can tell if it rejected or fulfilled in firstResult.status
);
```

I'm not a huge fan of the semantics here - but I've tried to keep them as close as possible to jQuery's semantics for `$.when`.

(1. or deferreds which are also promises in jQuery)